Corn snake aggression
I was wondering why my corn snake attacks when I have anything white in hand. I feed her frozen white mice once a week. I have had her for over 6 years now. When I got her from some one, I started her in a 10 gal tank. Now, she resides in a 40 gal tank. I was wondering is she attacking the white because of the mice. I also never been bitten by her.
